# Как ipa file загрузить в Iphone

Tags: objective-c, swift

Coздали ipa file в Xcode 8.2 на стороне без developer acounta,я пытаюсь загрузить в Itunes и синхронизироваться(чтобы потестить, посмотреть как работает). Но ничего подобного в Itunes(чтобы синхронизироватся) не нашел. Не подскажите кто как загружает ipa file  в iphone для тестирования.

Comment: Эмулятор же есть в XCode

Comment: без xcode , через itunes

Comment: вообще по  идее дабл тап на ipa сама тебе откроет itunes, привяжи телефон, чтобы itunes его увидел, зайди в приложения и найдешь свой апп. Там будет установить.

Comment: Только установить там нету? может я что то делаю не так? может не праильно создали ipa file? Или нельзя без developer program (99$)

Comment: Установите xcode и тогда сможете установить ipa через device меню в xcode.

Comment: Через Xcode понятно, просто я хочу отдать проект заказчику о он хочет его потестить(без xcode и девелопер аккаунт), поэтому создавал ipa file чтоб он потом через itunes себе загрузил и посмотрел.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, ipa без подписи девелоперского аккаунта все равно не запустится на реальном устройстве. А вот на эмуляторе - может.

Comment: Вы можете попробовать распространять ipa-файлы по схеме ad-hoc: https://habrahabr.ru/post/190296/

Comment: Используйте testflight или же fabric для таких целей. Вы можете сделать билд и пригласить заказчика как тестера для вашего приложения.